Transporting an inflatable SUP by train and bike, while being able to look over my shoulder
I have a trip coming up where I'm trying to avoid a really tedious drive, by getting there by train and bike.  But I'd like to take my inflatable SUP (Stand Up Paddle Board).
The problem is its backpack isn't safe for cycling on the roads I'll need to ride (or, IMO, any roads shared with traffic) because I can't see over my shoulder.  It's so wide it even interferes with the view in my bar-end mirror, which anyway I regard as sufficient for awareness, but not for a final check before pulling out into traffic.
I have a bike trailer, but that's completely out of the question for this trip - they're banned on the train.
I have some pretty big panniers, but, like almost all such things, they get quite narrow at the bottom, so the rolled up board wouldn't sit right down.  Anyway it should really sit lower than they allow.
So what solutions are there to carry a deflated SUP on the bike itself (in this case a 10'x32" Aquaplanet).  I'll have to carry my pump and accessories, and camping gear, but the ride is only 10-15km each way and my touring bike can carry a lot. Ideally a solution would also adapt to the tandem - even if I carry one on my back, my stoker  (my daughter) couldn't.
I've mocked something up by balancing it on the back of the tandem (as that currently has the heavy duty rack).

This is the overhang widthways.

And this is it wedged under the saddle lengthways, otherwise it would have tipped off the back.
The packed board is just under a metre in length (about 38"), which is more than the gaps in much of our cycle infrastructure.  If mounting vertically I'd want something rigid extending past half way up, but that could be the paddle sections.  The centres of gravity and pressure (as it will be a bit of a sail in crosswinds) need to be kept fairly low.

I wonder if a flat board couldn't be rigged on a rear luggage rack.  Weight of a SUP is not that high that it can't ride on the rear.  But putting it directly on the the narrow rack would be very unstable - hence first sitting a rigid board somehow fastened/cinched to the rack then bag laid out on top length-wise.  If you did do this though, can't see getting much more load on the rear so it would have to a be SUP + very little else on the trip.  I have both a bike and SUP and been - idly - pondering this for a while, after a few seawall trips with it just bungeed up in back.  Which is iffy.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica if this is really different from my answer, board on top of panniers with extra support if needed, please post as an answer. If not really different why posted as q comment at all?

@Willeke Because I am not sure if it would work, so I wouldn't necessarily hold it as an answer.  My focus hasn't been on SUP + camping so I wouldn't use, empty, panniers.  But I do know it balances very badly on the rear by itself, from experience.

You would not use empty panniers, you would use full ones that support the load above, which may rest on a rack.

@Willeke not just full, I think, but filled quite carefully and evenly. to the right height. I liked your supporting board idea better though

What's an SUP??

@PeteBecker it's a stand-up paddleboard. But at least round here SUP is the more common term than the full form. As you've had to ask, and someone else edited the full term into the question body (rightly - I should have included it myself), I wonder if the abbreviation isn't common everywhere

Sorry to be picky, but is "while being able to look over my shoulder" so necessary in the title? I would have thought that a SUP-in-backpack on a bike would obviously be a non-solution. Much less obvious is the "no trailer" restriction, because "use a trailer" was my first thought as a solution, without reading the full Q.

@MartinF, yes, it's a absolute requirement for being able to ride safely on busy roads.

@ChrisH I suspect that for people who know about them more than a passing mention, the acronym is probably common enough. I actually didn’t know the meaning either, but used context clues + Google to be sure enough to edit in the meaning to your question (and I figured that you’d roll it back if I was incorrect). I know of stand up paddle boards, and know a couple people who have used one while on vacation, but haven’t actually discussed them enough for an acronym to be needed or commonplace.

@fyrepenguin I suspect you're right, and it says something about the people I know (even in work) that they are well known. But given that I often have to tell students to spell out acronyms when they're first encountered, I was probably due to make the same mistake - so thanks for the proof-reading

The holiday cyclists I often see have two panniers and on top, supported by both, the biggest item.
This is often a tent or a roll with bedding.
In your case I would transport the sub there, possibly with a supporting board under it.
This board can be mounted on the rack or attached to the full panniers.
You will have to take the luggage off in the train, so your panniers, and if used the board, have to be taken of easily enough.
I assume you have a rear carrier rack, otherwise you will have to install something to carry the panniers.
If you want to transport the SUP vertical as you indicate in the comments you can fix a crate on the rack, with the SUP filling most of the space, even more than the box in this photo. And you will need space between the crate and the rack to mount your panniers or an easy release system for the crate, so you can still carry the panniers and take them off when needed like in the train.

You can even go the whole way, use a front carrier, like in this photo, if you are tall enough to still look over the load.

Photos made by me, bike owned by a coworker, crate and box by the company.

It's a good point, and I'll take some measurements. I'm concerned about overhang as the long dimension is over 80cm, which either makes me rather wide, or hangs off the back (my preference). I'd swap to my sturdy touring rack rather than my narrow commuting one. Now I wonder if I can use something else I'm carrying anyway for lateral support, like a section of paddle or my tent poles.

While getting the boards out I quickly took some pictures giving an idea of the proportions. Lengthways might be worth a test ride. Widthways it wouldn't fit through the barriers in the bike path to my local river.

I think I would trust widthwise more, so consider how much of a hinder those barriers are and how well you (or on the tandem your daughter) can move the legs if the board is tucked under so close.

The barriers I'm thinking of would mean stopping, taking it off, going through, then putting it back on. I'd move it further back than wedged under the saddle, with plenty of strapping, so it should be clear of legs. But I'm still thinking about ways to get it vertical

@MartinF it is a box in a crate, sitting still so nothing 'happens', just as OP wants nothing to happen with the SUP while being transported.

Unclear how the box is attached to the bike in he first photo...

It is not attached to a bike, it is an illustration of what I mean by a crate and the contents of it fitting.

If I could find a deep and strong enough crate, that wasn't too wide, that's the way I'd go.  I'm currently thinking I'll have to make a frame to work like that.  I'm tall, but would still have to put the board sideways on a pizza rack as shown. So I'd have to stop and remove it in a few places on the local bike paths, walking the bike through plenty of others

Does the claim, "You will have to take the luggage off in the train," apply universally?  I'd guess it depends on the train operator (and perhaps on the type of rolling stock and/or how busy it is).

It is the rule on all trains I am familiar with. But it does indeed depend on the train company, their rules, the bike spaces in the trains and whether you can just roll your bike in or have to lift it. Most UK trains have quite a step up into the train and a top heavy fully loaded bike will be awkward to get in.
